# Modifying YAML content

Tags: python, yaml

I have a YAML file like below. The file contains some special characters like "---", so I am unable to load the YAML in python using `yaml.load()` method.

```yaml
_engine: E1
_parameter:
- capacity:
  - updated: 20200825
    dependent: []
---
_engine: E2
_parameter:
- capacity:
  - updated: 20200826
    dependent: [D1,D2]
```

How come the YAML contents can be changed like below in python. It will be encapsulated under a tag `mainData` and `stage1`, `stage2` etc. Means for each "---", `stage<number value>` will increase.

```yaml
mainData:
stage1:
_engine: E1
_parameter:
- capacity:
  - updated: 20200825
    dependent: []
stage2:
_engine: E2
_parameter:
- capacity:
  - updated: 20200826
    dependent: [D1,D2]
```

Finally the end stream will also be a YAML only.

Comment: I guess you'll have to manually look for a line of dashes and replace it. Then parse the result as yaml. Have you tried that? What happened? Or you could find out why you have to deal with broken yaml files in the first place.

Comment: The three hyphens mark a new document in YAML. See https://www.yaml.info/learn/document.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `---` is part of YAML syntax. In short it indicates the beginning of a new document: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#YAML

Technically it is actually the "end of directives" line, but if the YAML document does not include any directives then it is effectively the same as "begin a new document". This allows multiple YAML documents to be concatenated together. With PyYAML you can iterate over all documents in a file using `yaml.load_all`. If you want to associate a "stage" index with each document, just do:

```
for stage_num, stage in enumerate(yaml.load_all(fileobj)):
   ...
```

If you wanted to convert this to a single document you could do something like

```
stages = {} 
for n, stage in enumerate(yaml.load_all(fileobj)):
    stages[f'stage{n}'] = stage
```

Then dump `stages` to a YAML file.

But I wanted to be clear that this data already has a valid structure too, so there isn't strictly any need to modify it.

Comment: I am using version 3.4.4 and getting error with the line stages[f'stage{n}'] = stage as Invalid syntax

Comment: Python 3.4 doesn't have f-strings.

Comment: Python 3.4 is also not supported anymore since quite a while. You should update to at least python 3.6.

Comment: I just tried using load_all instead of load and tried to print the yaml. Instead of printing the actual "<generator object load_all `some_address`>

Comment: it works after converting the o/p to list. e.g. print(list(yaml.load_all(yaml_data)))

Comment: Yes it is a generator. You can iterate over it with a for loop like in my example, or pass it to `list` if you want a list.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it

```
import itertools

with open('/path/to/input.yml') as infile, open('/path/to/output.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("mainData:\n")
    stage = itertools.count(1)

    for line in infile:
        if not line.startswith('---'):
            outfile.write(line)
            continue
        outfile.write(f"stage{next(stage)}:\n")
```